# virtocommerce An error occured while updating cart

Tags: virtocommerce

I have create a new store and add new physical item under category. when i click on item add to cart it shows me error?

[image]

[image]

[image]

How i can add item to cart..?

Comment: Can you tell your version of VirtoCommerce manager? You can find it in a lower left corner of a screen.

Comment: I am using version: 2.6.1173, Do you have any log file so that i may can specify the exact bug..?

Comment: You can find an error details in the response body with the browser network traffic monitoring tool for add-to-cart POST-request. Notifications with an error details (such as exception callstack an so on) for storefront requests was enabled in the next versions (2.7.x), unfortunately - not in 2.6.x. Can you update your question with error details for this request?

Comment: I have added error details can you please check that.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for updating your question. Seems that your product has no any images, so just add some primary image for your product and try to add it to shopping cart again. The presence of product primary image is necessary condition for now - as you can see an exception was occurred while converting your product to shopping cart line item at 22 line - product property `PrimaryImage` is `null`.

Comment: @atiksarker You are welcome! Can I ask you to mark this post as answer?